# Gradle: Only resolve dependencies for the desired variant

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have a test app with three flavors:

- dev: Uses a local copy of the library during development
- qa: Uses a snapshot during QA
- rc: Uses a prerelease build for release candidate testing.

---

```
dependencies {
  devCompile project(':library')
  qaCompile 'com.example:library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
  rcCompile 'com.example:library:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

I run Gradle, and expect it to do the minimum amount of work necessary to build just what I want:

```
./gradlew :test-app:connectedAndroidTestDevDebug
```

However, the build fails, because it is trying to resolve dependencies for all build flavors, not just the one I am building.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':test-app'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':test-app:_qaDebugCompile'.
>
> Could not find com.example:library1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
>
> ```
> Searched in the following locations:
>      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
>      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.aar
>      http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>      http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
>      http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.aar
>      file:/opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>      file:/opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
>      file:/opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.aar
>      file:/opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>      file:/opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
>      file:/opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/example/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.aar
>  Required by:
>      project-name:test-app:unspecified
> ```

The SNAPSHOT that the `qa` flavor is trying to resolve doesn't exist yet, and that should be fine, because I'm not trying to build the `qa` flavor. If that SNAPSHOT build is present, then everything works fine.

Questions:

1. Why are all build flavors having their dependencies resolved?
2. How can I accomplish building just one flavor without encountering this problem?
3. Is there some better way to do this that will be more "Gradley"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by checking the list of tasks and if there is a task for the desired build variant, adding the dependency.

```
dependencies {
  gradle.startParameter.taskRequests.each { taskRequest ->
    taskRequest.args.each { taskName ->
      String flavorName = "qa";
      if (taskName.toLowerCase().endsWith(flavorName+"debug") ||
          taskName.toLowerCase().endsWith(flavorName+"release")) {
        qaCompile 'com.example:my-library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
      }
    }
  }
  devCompile project(':localLibrary')
//qaCompile 'com.example:my-library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar' // What I used to do.
  rcCompile 'com.example:my-library:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

Keep in mind that the task list will not contain dependent task names, so if you aren't invoking a task that contains your build flavor name, it won't work. This is just something I got working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the build works if you exclude the task manually?

```
gradle connectedAndroidTestDevDebug -x _qaDebugCompile
```

It looks like the task `connectedAndroidTestDevDebug` has a dependency on the task `_qaDebugCompile`, which causes your problem. I don't know how your tasks are defined, but you can study your dependencies using Gradle's built-in tasks `gradle dependencies` and `gradle dependencyInsight`. Maybe that will give you a hint in the right direction:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency com.example:library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

You can read more about task dependencies in [the gradle User's guide](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html%20the%20Gradle%20user's%20guide).